# Cannot update a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm trying to update a variable with the result of a function, so it can be referenced elsewhere, but it doesn't update.

```
var total = 0;

mainQuery.count({
    success: function (number) {
        console.log("results",number);
        total = number;
    }
});

console.log("total is",total);

// console output:
// results 164
// total is 0
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: That looks like an asynchronous callback function?

Comment: Yes that looks like asynchronous callback, you need to do your job inside success callback function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, your `mainQuery.count()` function is asynchronous and runs `success` callback once it ends to run. However, you call `console.log()` after registring callback, but not after success function ends to run. What you should do is to run `console.log()` after success callback:

```
var total = 0;

mainQuery.count({
    success: function (number) {
        console.log("results",number);
        total = number;
        myFn();
    }
});

function myFn() {
    console.log("total is",total);
}
```

Comment: To add to the explanation, here's a great example I read recently: The call to `count()` is like putting some eggs on to boil. The `success` handler is like an alarm for when they're done cooking to slice them up. If you try to use the eggs before the alarm goes off, you get a very messy sandwich!

Answer (score 4):

As @Blazemonger said, `success` might be an asynchronous function. The output of `console.log("total is",total);` might be rendered before success even assigns `total` a value

Answer (score 1):

This code should work this way.
Checkout "closures" This is what you are doing. A Closure in short means, you are accessing a variable out of another context.

This is basically the same thing:

```
<script>
var test = 0;
setTimeout(function() { test = 10; }, 1000);
</script>
```

And it works. ^^

Your problem may be, that you are accessing the variable, before your asynchronous function returns

Comment: Thanks. Reading up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the overall scope of the variable `total`, it's difficult to answer, but to cover all bases you could do this...

```
window.total = 0;

mainQuery.count({
    success: function (number) {
        console.log("results",number);
        window.total = number;
    }
});

console.log("total is", window.total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;

mainQuery.count({
    success: function (number) {
        console.log("results",number);
        total = number;
        console.log("total is",total);
    }
});

//The code you had here is executed before the async-call is done. So it hasnt updated total with the value yet.

// console output:
// results 164
// total is 0
```